# How can I prevent from adding duplicate on a list in React?

Tags: if-statement, react-hooks

Hello all knowledgeable and talented SO members :)

I hope you can help me with this one too. I wish to do the following:

1. on submit check if the item is already on the list
2. if yes show an alert, and NOT add
3. if NO add the item to the list
   After searching online, I came up with the following code

```js
  const submitHandler = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const newScorer = e.target.value;
    const existingScorer = players.includes(newScorer);

    if (existingScorer) {
       console.log('already on list!');
    } else {
      const newPlayer = {id: nanoid(4), nummer: number};
      setPlayers([...players, newPlayer]);
      setNumber('');
    }
  };
```

The problem is that it does not work, adds even though "newScorer" is already on the list!?!

Thanks in advance

Regards
Peter

Comment: Thanks Janez for editing:)

Comment: Unrelated but should the key of the neePlayer object be 'number' and not 'nummer'?  I cant see why the simpe if/else wouldnt work, add a return after the console.log and it should work though

Comment: Looks like `players` is an array of objects. But `includes` is just checking if a single value is in there. Also `number` doesn't seem to be defined, so it's hard to tell what you're trying to do there.

Comment: Thanks Dan!
Unfortunately adding return did not help, still not working... :-(

Comment: @Bafsky: yes players is an array of objects. Should I use ```filter()````
number is defined, and is working.
I attach the a github link: https://github.com/peter-lelkes/indiv-points. Maybee it´s easier to help if you see all files

Comment: What do you want `existingScorer` to check for? If the current value of `number` is in the array?

Comment: @Bafsky I want to check if the `number` entered in the input
is already in the `players`array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments, you want to check if `number` is in the `players` array so...

```
const existingScorer = players.find(player => player.nummer === number);
```

... assuming `nummer` is correct property.

Comment: Thank you very much. Now it works as I thought / wanted:D

Comment: After rewriting the code, it suddenly does not work:
`const addHandler = () => {
  const existingScorer = players.find((player) => player.number === number);
 if(existingScorer){
   console.log('exist')
 } else {
   setPlayers([...players, {
    id: players.length,
    number: +number,

  
  }])
 }
 What does not work is that even if the player number already exists, it is re-entered, with a new ID
  setNumber('')
 
  
}`

Comment: [link](https://codepen.io/lelkes/pen/yLMOKLw?editors=0010)

Comment: Why do you have `number: +number`? That will increment the number before adding it to the list. Just use `number: number`.

Comment: I have `number: +number` because when sorting, if I do not have, the sorting will not work. I.e number 15 sorts between 1 & 2

Comment: Well that will turn 1 into 2 etc which is why it's not working. So that's not what you want. Sounds like you want to convert a string into a number which you can do with `parseInt`.

Comment: I was taught by Max @Udemy that instead of `parseInt`I can use `+ `
But in your opinion, I should write:
 `number: parseInt(number)`

Comment: My fault. I was thinking of `++number`. `+number` is actually fine. The problem is that you are comparing the numbers before you convert so it never finds a match. Try this... `const existingScorer = players.find((player) => player.number === +number);`

Comment: Glad to help. Please select this as the answer :)

Comment: gladly, but how?